# How to render EEG data in to HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is there any way to supply the EEG data in to HTML5 by using canvas or any other packages? OR Is there any API which will used to get EEG data into HTML5?

Any suggestions...

Comment: Yup. Step slowly away from the computer until your brain is functioning well again. Of _course_ there is. You get your data and you map it to a viewport. Amplitude is the (inverted) Y axis, time is the X axis.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: You have a maximum (& minimum) signal value - you must display this in the height of the canvas. You also have a period of time for which you'd like to display the graph - this must appear in the width of the canvas. It's a simple line-drawing on the canvas. Go forth and code! Line drawing on the canvas is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting example drawing a wave form for you to learn from.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4xMtc/

[image]

The canvas pans the screen to always show the newest leading data.

The example uses a simple sine wave, but you can plug your EEG into the data[] array and then your EEG wave will draw.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // capture incoming socket data in an array
    var data=[];

    // TESTING: fill data with some test values
    for(var i=0;i<5000;i++){
        data.push(Math.sin(i/10)*70+100);
    }

    // x is your most recent data-point in data[]
    var x=0;

    // panAtX is how far the plot will go rightward on the canvas
    // until the canvas is panned

    var panAtX=250;

    var continueAnimation=true;
    animate();


    function animate(){

        if(x>data.length-1){return;}

        if(continueAnimation){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        if(x++<panAtX){

            ctx.fillRect(x,data[x],1,1);

        }else{

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            // plot data[] from x-PanAtX to x 

            for(var xx=0;xx<panAtX;xx++){
                var y=data[x-panAtX+xx];
                ctx.fillRect(xx,y,1,1)
            }
        }
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will and let you know

Comment: Which algorithm are we using to get the output. Can you please suggest some good blogs to read about it more

Comment: @Manju The output algorithm is simple--(1) erase the canvas, (2)  redraw all the previous data 1 pixel to the left of where it was previously drawn and (3) draw one new data point at the end.  The incoming data is just test data.  It is a sine wave mapped with an increasing X.  Sine waves are nice for test data because they always range from 0.00 to 1.00. You would, of course, substitute your actual EEG data.

Comment: So will it possible for actual EEG data instead of continuous wave form as shown in above example?

Comment: Absolutely, just substitute your actual EEG data for the test data.